# 22.04 Nvidia Driver update problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, 22.04

Currently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Usually, when there's a new software update that includes updates for Nvidia drivers, after updating and rebooting, I get stuck on something like `dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks`.

To resolve the issue, I usually go to recovery mode, enable networking, and use the command `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, then reboot. Once I reach my desktop, I open Software & Updates, select a 'proprietary & tested' driver under the 'Additional Drivers' tab, and reboot again.

However, this time, although I haven't tried it with all proprietary drivers, it gets stuck all over again when I select 535 or 530 and reboot. I wonder if this is happening because of some kernel update, but I have no idea how to resolve this now. Is it possible to roll back to before I pressed that update button?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because it helped with other Nvidia and kernel related problems after recent updates: Apply this command and reboot. Then try again.

> sudo dkms autoinstall